# C fprintf with colors

Tags: c, linux, file, ubuntu

is there a way to print colored text to files using C programming language on Ubuntu Linux, you can use color codes with printf() and print colored text to console or terminal window, but how to print text to text files with colors?

Comment: Coloured output is a matter of the terminal emulation used, not a matter of c of printf. Better use termcap a/o ncurses or something similar

Comment: Those codes you refer to are meaningful only in the context of a terminal.  If you dump the file to terminal you'll see the same colors... but there's no such thing as "colored text" in a text file per se.

Comment: Most terminals can print colored output and e.g. ` printf("\033[33;1mBold Yellow\033[0m)"` will print "Bold Yellow" in bold yellow.

Comment: @ikrabbe Thank you for your comment

Comment: @JensMunk Thank you for your comment

Comment: @FatalError Thank you for this answer, you saved me time and effort, so there is no colors in text files, plain text files in C, it has a meaning only in terminal.

Comment: @BelalMedhat You are welcome. I have posted some code extracted from my local tools. I have a C version also. I find it very convenient to operate with both faces and colors using streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't, the long answer is you need to write some kind of mark-up along with your text in on of many formats that are available. There is no universal standard that you can use, so you'll need to pick one.

The colour codes are specific to the console and are not useful for printing, if you are just re-displaying the text back to the screen, no problem, but if you want to print it then you'll need to do some work.

The easiest may be to write HTML tags for viewing in a browser and print from there. Writing to the printer using the printer's mark-up codes is also possible and it can be simple (or next to impossible) on some printers. The down side is this is a printer specific solution. If you're really ambitious output in PDF format (it's just text), RTF or any other document format but that will take time and skills.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I will take the short answer, no colors in plain text c on linux, because it was made so simple to read and write, everything in Linux is a file, so if i want to print text with colors, either in terminal or print to text file and add HTML tags and specify colors for text.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this solution, which is pretty neat if you are into streams and C++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace sps {
  namespace colors {
    enum color {
      none    = 0x00,
      black   = 0x01,
      red     = 0x02,
      green   = 0x03,
      yellow  = 0x04,
      blue    = 0x05,
      magenta = 0x06,
      cyan    = 0x07,
      white   = 0x08
    };
  }
  namespace faces {
    enum face {
      normal    = 0x00,
      bold      = 0x01,
      dark      = 0x02,
      uline     = 0x04,
      invert    = 0x07,
      invisible = 0x08,
      cline     = 0x09
    };
  }

  /**
   * Generate string for color codes for std::iostream's
   *
   * @param foreground
   * @param background
   *
   * @return
   *
   * Usage:
   *
   * using namespace sps;
   * std::cout << "These words should be colored [ "
   *           << set_color(colors::red)   << "red "
   *           << set_color(colors::green) << "green "
   *           << set_color(colors::blue)  << "blue"
   *           << set_color() <<  " ]" << std::endl;
   *
   */
  static inline std::string set_color(sps::colors::color foreground = sps::colors::none,
                                      sps::colors::color background = sps::colors::none) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "\033[";
    if (!foreground && ! background){
        s << "0"; // reset colors if no params
    }
    if (foreground) {
        s << 29 + foreground;
        if (background) s << ";";
    }
    if (background) {
        s << 39 + background;
    }
    s << "m";
    return s.str();
  }

  /**
   *
   *
   * @param face
   *
   * @return
   */
  static inline std::string set_face(sps::faces::face face = sps::faces::normal) {
    std::stringstream s;
    s << "\033[";
    if (!face) {
        s << "0"; // reset face
    }
    if (face) {
      s << face;
    }
    s << "m";
    return s.str();
  }
}

int main(int agrc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace sps;
  std::cout << "These words should be colored [ "
        << set_color(colors::red)   << "red "
        << set_color(colors::green) << "green "
        << set_color(colors::blue)  << "blue "
        << set_color(colors::cyan)   << "cyan "
        << set_color(colors::magenta) << "magenta "
        << set_color(colors::yellow)  << "yellow"
        << set_color() <<  " ]" << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That is amazing, Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry for not including any faces in the example, but these work as well, e.g. `<< set_face(faces::bold) << "Bold"` gives a bold face.

Comment: Thanks, I usually write in C but C++ sometimes has a cleaner way of organizing the code.

Comment: I can update it with a version for C, but it should be pretty clear to do in C. Make functions operating on char buffers and append and prepend the desired stuff.

Comment: @BelalMedhat If you write a solution in C and upload an answer, I will remove mine and upvote yours

Comment: Thank you, I did it in C, this is more than enough, Thank you for your help, this is amazing code.

Comment: No, my c code just use ansi c color codes to print text using colors in terminals and consoles, and I've learned it from answers on stackoverflow, your code is very good and in C++.

Comment: Just thought that the answer in here should be given in ANSI-C, since that was your question :-). I didn't print my C version, since I use some C99 features which are not available on Windows. We just leave it here, I will go get a pizza.

Comment: LOL Go and get pizza, i'm happy that i met you, Thank you again.